# Is there a word for the second part of a story title after a main character?

Tags: word-usage

I commonly see the format:

> *Main Character(s)* and *some other important idea*

Story titles:

- Harry Potter and **the Goblet of Fire**
- Alexander and **the Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Day**
- The Three Little Pigs and **the Somewhat Bad Wolf**

Band names:

- Johnny Cash and **the Tennessee Two**
- Fitz and **the Tantrums**
- Florence and **the Machine**

And even slight variants:

- Sex and **the City**

Is there a name for this common construction?

Do the two parts have technical names?

Comment: Also: this is my first time asking a question here, and I'm not sure if the "question" part of my question is acceptable, since my actual question is slightly more generalized.

Comment: Sex is not the name of a character, so the last doesn't fit the trope at all.

Comment: As far as literary titles go, this pattern seems to apply mainly to children's books (Charlie and the Chocolate Factory is another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that this title formula is really common! But after searching for quite a while I haven't been able to define a definitive name for the formula or a term for the second phrase.

Some names for the formula as a whole:

- [The X and the Y](http://www.wattpad.com/18230883-much-ado-about-writing-i-need-a-title)
- [The This and the That](http://danspira.com/meme-collection/the-this-and-the-that-all-time-greatest-metaphorical-book-titles/)
- [X and the Ys](https://allthetropes.orain.org/wiki/A_Good_Name_for_a_Rock_Band#X_And_The_Ys)
- [A, B and other Cs](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/06/my_next_book_ti.html)
- [Couplet](http://www.dancohen.org/2010/08/04/crowdsourcing-the-title-of-my-next-book/)

Answer (score 0):

The word "noun phrase" is a word for all of second parts of the items you list, but I suspect you may be looking for something more specific.

The first element of each example is  a noun ("Fitz") or noun phrase {"Harry Potter") and a second noun phrase ("the Tantrums"), or ("the goblet of fire"), connected with a conjunction.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for a grammatical term, but something specific to this style of title.

Comment: @Barmar is correct: I'm looking for a more specific term.